# Getting intermittent long running queries in Apache IGNITE

Tags: performance, inner-join, ignite

Receiving intermittent LRQ's in IGNITE, the same query runs perfectly fine the whole day. But receiving LRQ's sometimes and which create huge spike in response times and affect platform.

We are using Ignite version 2.7.5 and we are using partitioning with 256 partitions in each node and got two nodes which are communicating with each other in UDP multicast mode.

RAM is 210GB, persistence mode enabled and other configurations are as below:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <!-- Enable annotation-driven caching. -->


    <bean name="noOpFailureHandler" class="org.apache.ignite.failure.NoOpFailureHandler"/>
    <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>
        <property name="igniteInstanceName" value="PincodeGrid"/>
        <property name="clientMode" value="false"/>
        <property name="failureDetectionTimeout" value="80000"/>
        <property name="clientFailureDetectionTimeout" value="120000"/>
        <property name="systemWorkerBlockedTimeout" value="30000" />
        <property name="longQueryWarningTimeout" value="3000"/>
        <property name="failureHandler" ref="noOpFailureHandler"/>
        <property name="metricsLogFrequency" value="#{600 * 10 * 1000}"/>
        <property name="rebalanceThreadPoolSize" value="16"/>
        <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
                <!-- Redefining the default region's settings -->
                <property name="pageSize" value="#{4 * 1024}"/>
                <!--<property name="writeThrottlingEnabled" value="true"/>-->
                <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                        <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                        <property name="initialSize" value="#{105L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                        <property name="name" value="Default_Region"/>
                        <!--Setting the size of the default region to 4GB. -->
                        <property name="maxSize" value="#{120L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                        <property name="checkpointPageBufferSize"
                                  value="#{4096L * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                        <!--<property name="pageEvictionMode" value="RANDOM_2_LRU"/>-->
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="walPath" value="/wal/pincode"/>
                <property name="walArchivePath" value="/wal/pincode/archive"/>
                <property name="storagePath" value="/ignite/persistence"/>
                <property name="checkpointFrequency" value="180000"/>
                <property name="checkpointThreads" value="8"/>
                <property name="walMode" value="BACKGROUND"/>
                <property name="walSegmentSize" value="#{1L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                <!--<property name="authenticationEnabled" value="true"/>-->
            </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                        <property name="multicastGroup" value="224.0.0.180"/>
                        <property name="multicastPort" value="47514"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>

            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="communicationSpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi">
                <property name="messageQueueLimit" value="2048"/>
                <property name="socketWriteTimeout" value="10000"/>
                <property name="connectionsPerNode" value="10"/>
                <property name="usePairedConnections" value="true"/>
                <property name="socketReceiveBuffer" value="#{64L * 1024}"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

And here is the query which is becoming an LRQ.

````
SPS__Z1.PRIORITY __C0_0,
LOGISTIC__Z2.CODFLAG __C0_1,
LOGISTIC__Z2.CODLIMIT __C0_2,
LOGISTIC__Z2.PREPAIDLIMIT __C0_3,
LOGISTIC__Z2.SLAVEID __C0_4,
STOCKROOM__Z0.ORDERCUTOFFTIMESDD __C0_5,
STOCKROOM__Z0.ORDERCUTOFFTIMEED __C0_6,
STOCKROOM__Z0.ORDERCUTOFFTIMEHD __C0_7,
LOGISTIC__Z2.LOGISTICSID __C0_8,
LOGISTIC__Z2.LOGISTICPRIORITY __C0_9
FROM "SellerPincodeServiceabilityCache".SELLERPINCODESERVICEABILITY SPS__Z1 
 INNER JOIN "LogisticsServiceabilityCache".LOGISTICSSERVICEABILITY LOGISTIC__Z2 
 ON TRUE 
 INNER JOIN "StockRoomLocationCache".STOCKROOMLOCATIONS STOCKROOM__Z0 
 ON TRUE
WHERE (LOGISTIC__Z2.PREPAIDLIMIT >= ?3) AND ((LOGISTIC__Z2.ISLOGISTICACTIVE = 'Y') AND ((LOGISTIC__Z2.ISFRAGILE = ?8) AND ((LOGISTIC__Z2.ISPRECIOUS = ?7) AND ((LOGISTIC__Z2.DELIVERYMODE = ?6) AND ((LOGISTIC__Z2.TRANSPORTMODE = ?5) AND ((LOGISTIC__Z2.DESTNPINCODE = ?1) AND ((STOCKROOM__Z0.ACTIVE = 'Y') AND ((STOCKROOM__Z0.SELLERID = ?2) AND ((STOCKROOM__Z0.SLAVEID = LOGISTIC__Z2.SLAVEID) AND ((SPS__Z1.SLAVEID = LOGISTIC__Z2.SLAVEID) AND ((SPS__Z1.SHIPMENTTYPE = ?4) AND ((SPS__Z1.DELIVERYTYPE = ?6) AND ((SPS__Z1.PINCODE = ?1) AND (SPS__Z1.SELLERID = ?2))))))))))))))
ORDER BY 1, 10', plan=
SELECT
    SPS__Z1.PRIORITY AS __C0_0,
    LOGISTIC__Z2.CODFLAG AS __C0_1,
    LOGISTIC__Z2.CODLIMIT AS __C0_2,
    LOGISTIC__Z2.PREPAIDLIMIT AS __C0_3,
    LOGISTIC__Z2.SLAVEID AS __C0_4,
    STOCKROOM__Z0.ORDERCUTOFFTIMESDD AS __C0_5,
    STOCKROOM__Z0.ORDERCUTOFFTIMEED AS __C0_6,
    STOCKROOM__Z0.ORDERCUTOFFTIMEHD AS __C0_7,
    LOGISTIC__Z2.LOGISTICSID AS __C0_8,
    LOGISTIC__Z2.LOGISTICPRIORITY AS __C0_9
FROM "SellerPincodeServiceabilityCache".SELLERPINCODESERVICEABILITY SPS__Z1
    /* "SellerPincodeServiceabilityCache".SELLER_PINCODE_SERVICE_INDX: SHIPMENTTYPE = ?4
        AND DELIVERYTYPE = ?6
        AND PINCODE = ?1
        AND SELLERID = ?2
     */
    /* WHERE (SPS__Z1.SELLERID = ?2)
        AND ((SPS__Z1.PINCODE = ?1)
        AND ((SPS__Z1.SHIPMENTTYPE = ?4)
        AND (SPS__Z1.DELIVERYTYPE = ?6)))
    */
INNER JOIN "LogisticsServiceabilityCache".LOGISTICSSERVICEABILITY LOGISTIC__Z2
    /* "LogisticsServiceabilityCache".LOGISTICS_SERVICEABILITY_INDX: PREPAIDLIMIT >= ?3
        AND ISLOGISTICACTIVE = 'Y'
        AND ISFRAGILE = ?8
        AND ISPRECIOUS = ?7
        AND DELIVERYMODE = ?6
        AND TRANSPORTMODE = ?5
        AND DESTNPINCODE = ?1
        AND SLAVEID = SPS__Z1.SLAVEID
     */
    ON 1=1
    /* WHERE (SPS__Z1.SLAVEID = LOGISTIC__Z2.SLAVEID)
        AND ((LOGISTIC__Z2.DESTNPINCODE = ?1)
        AND ((LOGISTIC__Z2.TRANSPORTMODE = ?5)
        AND ((LOGISTIC__Z2.DELIVERYMODE = ?6)
        AND ((LOGISTIC__Z2.ISPRECIOUS = ?7)
        AND ((LOGISTIC__Z2.ISFRAGILE = ?8)
        AND ((LOGISTIC__Z2.PREPAIDLIMIT >= ?3)
        AND (LOGISTIC__Z2.ISLOGISTICACTIVE = 'Y')))))))
    */
INNER JOIN "StockRoomLocationCache".STOCKROOMLOCATIONS STOCKROOM__Z0
    /* "StockRoomLocationCache".STOCKROOMLOCATIONS_SLAVEID_IDX: SLAVEID = LOGISTIC__Z2.SLAVEID */
    ON 1=1
WHERE (LOGISTIC__Z2.PREPAIDLIMIT >= ?3)
    AND ((LOGISTIC__Z2.ISLOGISTICACTIVE = 'Y')
    AND ((LOGISTIC__Z2.ISFRAGILE = ?8)
    AND ((LOGISTIC__Z2.ISPRECIOUS = ?7)
    AND ((LOGISTIC__Z2.DELIVERYMODE = ?6)
    AND ((LOGISTIC__Z2.TRANSPORTMODE = ?5)
    AND ((LOGISTIC__Z2.DESTNPINCODE = ?1)
    AND ((STOCKROOM__Z0.ACTIVE = 'Y')
    AND ((STOCKROOM__Z0.SELLERID = ?2)
    AND ((STOCKROOM__Z0.SLAVEID = LOGISTIC__Z2.SLAVEID)
    AND ((SPS__Z1.SLAVEID = LOGISTIC__Z2.SLAVEID)
    AND ((SPS__Z1.SHIPMENTTYPE = ?4)
    AND ((SPS__Z1.DELIVERYTYPE = ?6)
    AND ((SPS__Z1.PINCODE = ?1)
    AND (SPS__Z1.SELLERID = ?2))))))))))))))
ORDER BY 1, 10
, parameters=[533233, 125112, 2480.0, TSHIP, SUR, HD, N, N]] ```
````

Comment: Indexes are present in all the tables and query is written according to index order only.

Comment: Could you share tables and indexes definitions and tables's sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this query is genuinely slow? Did you check how many rows does it return typically and how long does it take? Maybe you have some outlier `sellerId`'s for which it would run much longer?

Comment: We checked the query plan, it's good. Outlier seller id?

Comment: Seller it which has way more data than average

Comment: If the query is causing this problem every once in a while, maybe it's not the query itself but topology change or long checkpoint which triggers the issue, or something else

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Ignite may pause a query if a partition map exchange is imminent. If you do a lot of add node / remove node / add cache / remove cache operations, you may notice that some queries take way more time to run.